# How To Graph This Hopf Oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried using Wolfram to accomplish this with no success.

The equation for an oscillator *i* is:

$$\dot x_i = \alpha(\mu - r^2_i)x_i - w_iy_i$$

$$\dot y_i = \beta(\mu - r^2_i)y_i - w_ix_i$$

$$w_i = \frac{w_{stance}}{e^{-by}+1} + \frac{w_{swing}}{e^{by}+1}$$

$$where\quad r_i = \sqrt{x_i^2 + y_i^2},\sqrt\mu\ \ is\ the \ amplitude;\ w_i\ is\ the\ frequency;\ w_{stance},\ w_{swing}\ are\ durations;\ and\ \alpha,\beta,b\ are\ constants.$$

The paper these equations were taken from can be found [here](https://www.google.ca/url?url=http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/130727/files/sRutishauser08.pdf&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&sa=U&ved=0CCsQFjABahUKEwj1o4T8zJfHAhUGFz4KHflrBm4&usg=AFQjCNEVROqIjCOKNnPV6pDMMViW6a_Wuw).

I would appreciate an explanation of how the the frequency can be determined by a non-constant value i.e. when $w_{stance} = 2w_{swing}$, $w_i$ looks like a sigmoid function.

Also, my current understanding of oscillators is limited to sine waves. Please compare the oscillator described above to a sine wave i.e. which part of the equation is the phase, offset.

It seems bizarre to me that the frequency is ultimately subtracted from the amplitude. Please describe in layman's terms how this works.